# In Apache Spark, While running the ./spark-shell command im getting error and How to test MapR by distributing data

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, mapr

- I'm having 3 Ubuntu VM's
- In that I have configured and installed MapR with 3 VM's.
- 1 VM as Master and And 2 VM as slaves

In that I have installed the Java 9,

```
java version "9.0.1",Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11),Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
```

- And I have installed Scala,Scala code runner `version 2.11.6 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL`
- Then I have downloaded spark and untar the file then I have
  configured the slaves and `spark-env.sh` files.
- In slaves file,I have added the nodes VM's.

In `spark-env.sh`, I have added the paths,

```
    export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/ 
    export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=8 
    export SCALA_HOME=/usr/share/scala-2.11/ 
    export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=2 
    export SPARK_WORKER_DIR=/home/administrator/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7 
    export SPARK_MASTER_IP=192.168.4.140
```

like wise I have followed the steps shown in,
http://chennaihug.org/knowledgebase/spark-master-and-slaves-multi-node-installation/
https://data-flair.training/blogs/install-apache-spark-multi-node-cluster/comment-page-1/#comment-22441

After that while running the `./spark-shell` its showing error.

> In MapR?** How to Test the MapR, I have installed and configured with
>   3 VM's. But i want to test the MapR by distributing the data's in to
>   clusters VM's?

[image]

Comment: Spark doesn't support Java 9 yet. What version of Scala you use matters as well

Comment: Which version of Java it will support, already i have tried with Java 7 so thats y i have installed Java 9

Comment: 7 is end of life. Java 8 is the only version supported starting at Spark 2.2 I think

Comment: Versions are all  listed here. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/#downloading